# is first syllable stress on "frequent" becomming the norm for verb form?

Tags: pronunciation

several TV shows lately have put the stress on first syllable in the verb form of "frequent".  I looked up several dictionary/pronunciation sites and they only give first syllable emphasis option for noun and verb.  however other more esoteric sites confirm (what I assume to be) correct verb/noun difference.   any comments?

Comment: In BrE the stress is on the first syllable for the adjective **frequent** and the adverb **frequently**. It is in the second syllable for the verb **frequent**.

Comment: Could you link to the specific websites that you mention?

Answer (score 3):

For historical reference, Kenyon and Knott's 1949 *A Pronouncing Dictionary of American English* accents the second syllable of the verb [*frequent*](https://archive.org/details/pronouncingdicti00unse/page/175) with no other alternative. In the intervening years, however, more and more educated American speakers stress the first syllable so there is no difference between verb and adjective. Most online dictionaries, such as [Merriam-Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/frequent), give both pronunciations. I suspect that if an American speaker is going to accent the second syllable, it will more likely be in the past tense/participle *frequented* rather than the present tense or infinitive.